# Looking for a source for well done Purim Torah Gemaras

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, purim, humor

One example that is utterly irreverent yet very well done and funny is the [Simpsons episode done up as a blatt of gemera](http://www.e-ark.net/simpsons.html). (As a positive aspect, his use of B'Laz for Rav Shmuel David Ha'Tzair, as "Candyman" actually gave me insight into what the whole point of B'Laz means in Rashi).

Looking for other good online sources.   I know I had seen around yeshiva some little pamphlets each year at Purim, but no idea where to get them.

Edit: I looked at the PDF's linked of Mesechet Purim, but I was remembering one in Vilna Shas formatting.

Comment: theres also this. how do you post a pdf thats not online?

Comment: use the upload feature

Comment: see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) which has a large collection of purim torah.

Comment: I once wrote up a daf of fake gemara for Purim when I was in high school. But it's on an old computer that I don't have with me. Besides, a good portion of it relied on inside jokes specific to the characters of our yeshiva. Also, I would probably read it again after all this time just to be embarrassed at my own teenage Aramaic grammar.

Comment: I do remember, though, that one section of it involved a discussion between two guys named Yayin and Shechar, parodying the discussion between Sasson and Simcha in Maseches Succah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Classic" Purim Torah is called ["Megillas Sesorim and Maseches Purim"](http://hebrewbooks.org/37448). It was printed in 1871.

Comment: Clever, but I admit, not making me laugh.  So far seems like parody which is ok I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

here's one http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37448&pgnum=1
its מסכת פורים. there's another one called מסכת שיכורים but i haven't found it yet.

Comment: sorry thats the same as the previous post